# How can I store selenium webdriver tests results?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I would like to save the automated test results each time I run them.

I'm using selenium webdriver (more exactly: Protractor). I run a suite of tests then I see the results displayed in console: I would like to export them (which of them were successfully passed, which of them failed).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Protractor FAQ](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md) says:

> How do I produce an XML report of my test results?
>
> Use jasmine-reporters and add a JUnit XML Reporter. Check out [this
>   example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/junitOutputConf.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestNG + XSLT reports. It gives nice html reports. If you are using Ant then you can zip the file and email it to selected users after execution is completed. XSLT tells youif your Java method which is your test case, are Pass or Failed.

If you want to know each command Pass/Fail status then you log4j utility and do logging.

-Vinay